# Is it possible to process messages between 2 topics by using one stream in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

What I want to achieve is that, message `{'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male'}` into `topic1`. create a stream only interest in the the `name` attribute like `{'name': 'James'}` and sink to `topic2`.

From the [tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html#cp-quickstart-step-1), looks like I need 2 streams to move messages from topic1 to topic2 given `CREATE STREAM SELECT AS` can only select from streams/tables?

eg. create `stream1` that based on `topic1` and create `stream2` as select from `stream1` and sink to `topic2`

Is it possible to skip stream2?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to define a stream that parses the data into selectable fields. Then you need to select them to write to another. If you just want one process/topology running, then deploy a Kafka Streams application

Comment: I see thanks for answering